# how to cut character string with whitespace.. php

Tags: php

( sorry my bad english )
I try to cut a large character string with whitespace like this:

```
hola      como  estas    0001               hola 02hola    como   estas
```

well, I need to cut between 10 space and save that in a txt file.
some like this:

[enter link description here](http://fotos.subefotos.com/dc22ad9dc78ccf35f125fc50054b35c7o.jpg)

I try :

```
<?php
     $pago = $_POST["texto"];
     //$salto_de_linea = chr(13).chr(10);
     //$pago_a_txt = wordwrap($pago, 11, $salto_de_linea, false);
     //$pago_a_txt=preg_split('//', $pago, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
      $pago_a_txt=substr($pago, -610);
      $txt = fopen("file.txt", "w");
      fwrite($txt, $pago_a_txt);
      fclose($txt);
?>
```

Comment: `preg_split('/.{10}/', ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

`substr()` is the key to your answer here.

You will want to loop through the input string 10 characters at a time to create each line.

```
<?php
$input = 'hola como estas 0001 hola 02hola como estas';
$output = '';

$stringLength = strlen($input) / 10; // 10 is for number of characters per line
$linesProcessed = 0;

while ($linesProcessed < $stringLength) {
    $output .= substr($input, ($linesProcessed * 10), 10) . PHP_EOL;
    $linesProcessed++;
}
echo $output;
```

The output is:

```
hola como 
estas 0001
 hola 02ho
la como es
tas
```

(Note: Use `nl2br()` or use the CSS style `whitespace: pre` if you're displaying this in HTML).